# How do I know which Drupal 8 modules are supported by Drupal 8 versions?

Tags: 8

How do I know which Drupal 8 modules are supported by Drupal 8 versions?

For example is Page Manager 8.x-1.0-alpha8 module supported in every Drupal 8 version? And if not how do I know which Drupal 8 version supports some module?

Which version of Drupal 8 supports [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) 8.x-1.0-alpha2 module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only see which modules have a release that was at one point compatible with a pre-release of Drupal 8; you can't tell whether a module is actually still compatible without testing it - **unless** the maintainer explicitly mentioned it on the page.

For example, the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) project you asked for states:

> the alpha2 version is working with Drupal 8 beta 4. We try to keep the 8.x-1.x-dev branch compatible with the Drupal 8 HEAD.

You can make a good guess, though, using the module's activity and the [core release cycle](https://www.drupal.org/core/release-cycle): The older a module is, the more likely it is to be broken by a major API change. For example, the .info -> YAML switch (early 2013) broke all modules. The hook_menu() -> YAML switch (late 2013 / early 2014) broke all modules that have menu paths. Other APIs have been changed even more recently.

For example, the [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) project you asked about was last pushed yesterday, and the last alpha was released the same day as the last core beta. You have very good odds there.

> how do i know which Drupal 8 version supports some module?

Sorry to be blunt, but knowing this wouldn't really help you (unless you're working on porting the module, and need to know what to change). If the module isn't supported by the latest beta, then the last version that *did* support it is presumably an outdated and unstable pre-release. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> How do i know which drupal 8 modules are supported by Drupal 8 versions?

You can't.

Specific projects might release alpha/beta versions in sync with core but if that's so and which version requires which version is something you have to figure out for each project separately.

You can try to get guess based on the release date, check if a release came out before or after a beta version. But it might be that an older release still works.

No contrib project that I've seen so far explicitly defines version specific dependencies, and it's actually not really possible, because you don't know yet when you release whether the module is going to be compatible with the next beta or not and when something will break it.

That said, there should be fewer and fewer API changes that break contrib modules from now on.